# C# ASP.NET Core DI with logging

Tags: c#, asp.net, dependency-injection

I'm looking for DI solution for the following problem. I'm writing a custom SeriLog sync that requires a dependency from my serviceprovider. I can't seem to figure out how to access my serviceprovider from `services.AddLogging()`:

```
services.AddSingleton<ICosmosFactory, CosmosFactory>();
services.AddLogging((builder) =>
{
    var logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
        .MinimumLevel.Verbose()
        .WriteTo.AzureCosmosDB(
            client: sp.Client,
            databaseName: "MyDb",
            collectionName: "logging",
            timeToLive: TimeSpan.FromDays(7)
           )
        .CreateLogger();
            builder.AddSerilog(logger);
});
```

In this example, Serilogs Sync needs an instance of CosmosClient which is provided by CosmosFactory. The only way I can see to grab it is to do the following:

```
builder.Services.BuildServiceProvider()
```

This is not ideal as it could potentially create duplicates of my singleton services.

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea if this is the best approach. But playing around with it. I found the best way is to inject a ILoggerFactory as a singleton and configure that instead.

```
services.AddSingleton<ILoggerFactory>(sp =>
{
    var factory = new LoggerFactory();
    var logger = new LoggerConfiguration();
    Serilog.Events.LogEventLevel level = Serilog.Events.LogEventLevel.Debug;
    logger.WriteTo.AzureCosmosDB(
        client:((ICosmosFactory)sp.GetRequiredService(typeof(ICosmosFactory))).Client,
        databaseName: "Diagnostics",
        collectionName: "logging",
        timeToLive: TimeSpan.FromDays(logTTL),
        restrictedToMinimumLevel: level
        );
    return factory;
});
```

If someone has a better answer or a reason this isnt a good answer. Please let me know.

Comment: I am not seeing a relationship between the factory and the configured logger.

Comment: My understanding is, ILogger factory is what ConfigureLogging actually adds for dependency injection. When you request a logger to be injected into a service, it will use ILoggerFactory to create that logger for you. So by excluding "ConfigureLogging" and instead injecting ILoggerFactory manually, You get access to the correct service provider.

Comment: Yes, looking at the code in Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.AddLogging , it is doing something similar to what you have done: `services.TryAdd(ServiceDescriptor.Singleton<ILoggerFactory, LoggerFactory>());`